# Sending textfile from client to server and then back to client

Tags: java, client, server

I need some help from you guys. I'm new at networking and try to send a text file from a client to a server, **and then back to the client again.**

The code below works fine for the first step, sending the text file from client to server. The server receives the file, and adds something to it (not in this code).

Then my problem starts: How can I make the server send the text file back to client again, and have client receive it?

I really don't know how to do this. And also, can you tell me if I need to add a while loop to my code, if I want to send files back and forth many times?

Thanks

Client (Starts with sending a text file to server)

```
public class TClient {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 11111);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("send.txt");
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
    }       
}
```

Server (starts with receiving a text file from client)

```
public class TServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(11111);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("receive.txt");
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be done in the same way as sending... only this time the server will be one with `getOutputStream` and client with `getInputStream`

Comment: I have tried it that way, but it gives me errors. I'm not sure of how I can (or should) close streams and sockets, so it does not works for me. I have tried tons of ways, none of them working. As I'm said I'm new to this...

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Different depending on how the code looks like. Sometimes I get errors that the Connection is closed, and sometimes no errors but the received file on client side is empty.